# Store List of Places as Key Value pair with City name using C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, text-files, key-value-store, keyvaluepair

With My code I can Generate Lots of Places name from a Wikipedia article. Suppose if I look for Flensburg wikipedia page it will give all the external page links of places as name. So at this moment all the places are shown on output as list form like

```
Maasbüll
Bov Municipality
Hürup
Hürup(Amt)
Kupfermühle
.........and so on...
```

Now what I want to do is, I want to store all these places paired with its city name. Suppose here Flensburg is the city name. So i want to store it as following way-

```
Flensburg;Maasbüll;Bov Municipality;Hürup;Hürup(Amt);Kupfermühle.... so on..
```

My code to generate list of all places are as follows-

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=Flensburg&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var responseContent = response.Content;

                string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString).query.geosearch.Select(a => a.title).ToList();

                foreach (var item in obj)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }

             }


        }
```

I want to know how can I store my data like I mentioned.

Comment: @J... Could you please describe a ittle bit more how to proceed. I am very handling this case. Thank you

Comment: Harry, does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Sakura: Thank you very much, Now it is working. And could you please remove your another answer. Because may be it would be confusing for some other one. I added this two line below the console output. Please add this 2 line in your code also. as the question is to store the data in storage. Thank you very much for you time.var output = query + ";" + cities[query];
                    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\C# Visual Studio\City.txt", output);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> cities = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string query = "Flensburg";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(query) + "&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json").Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        var responseContent = response.Content;

        string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString).query.geosearch.Select(a => a.title).ToList();

        List<string> places = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
             places.Add(item);
        }
        cities[query] = string.Join(";", places);


       Console.WriteLine(query + ":" + cities[query]);
       var output = query + ";" + cities[query];
       File.WriteAllText(@"C:\C# Visual Studio\City.txt", output);
     }


}
```

Comment: Your code only shows the City name in alist not the Places name

Comment: I tried your code. but it gives a place name first and city name after that. Like Maasbüll Flensburg in this way, and it continued for every places. But I wante to to keep the city name at first and then all the places with ; basis. It is totally different

Comment: Yes I changed it But it shows output as Flensburg before every palces name ans also as list format not according to my expected result. there are 500 places and Flensburg is added before every place.

Comment: Everything with ; interval

Comment: it shows error- Error 5 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement for cities[query] in line Console.WriteLine(query + ": " cities[query]);

Comment: Thank you very much, Now it is working. And could you please remove your another answer. Because may be it would be confusing for some other one. I added this two line below the console output. Please add this 2 line in your code also. as the question is to store the data in storage. Thank you very much for you time.var output = query + ";" + cities[query];
                    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\C# Visual Studio\City.txt", output);

Answer (score 0):

As per your own tag, A [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) will do exactly what you want.

```
Dictionary<string, Object> cities = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
cities.Add(name, item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this -

```
var output = String.Join(";", obj );
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it joint every places with ;. Could you please give me hints how can I add City name before it

Comment: I have put item insted of object. Because while trying with object it does not give the correct answer. But after putting the item the string joint does not work.foreach (var item in obj)
                    {
                        var output = String.Join(";", item);
                        Console.WriteLine(output);
                    }

Comment: there is no `City` element in your `JSON`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<cityname,List<associated places>> d = new Dictionary<cityname,List<associated places>>();
```

key will be the city name that you search and value is a list which contains all the associated places

Add multiple places as values in a list with a single key of a dictionary.